# Why does Gensim reject to load supervised model dict built by Fasttext (Facebook) library?

Tags: gensim, fasttext

I was thinking underlying dictionary are the same for both supervised (classification) and unsupervised(Word Embedding). I want to analyze the classification model (word vectors) that I built for supervised problem using Gensim. But I got following error. I know **Gensim has not implemented Supervised learning** part of Fastext and only focusing on Word Embedding. But I just want to load the dictionary to analyze. Any pointers?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fasttext_model_analysis.py", line 2, in <module>
    model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('model_ups_tickets_rca.bin')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/fasttext_wrapper.py", line 274, in load_fasttext_format
    model.load_binary_data(encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/fasttext_wrapper.py", line 301, in load_binary_data
    self.load_dict(f, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/fasttext_wrapper.py", line 332, in load_dict
    raise NotImplementedError("Supervised fastText models are not supported")
NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported
```

Answer (score 3):

Gensim made the decision not to support the `-supervised` FastText mode, since Gensim's focus is unsupervised topic-modeling. And, as a result, it throws this early error when anyone tries to load such a FastText model, so as not to mislead users about things working, or have uninterpretable/corrupt half-read models in memory.

But, it might be reasonable to offer a load of just-the-word-vectors, without having the full model & classification options. (Merely reading those word-vectors, while ignoring the unsupported state, is probably a very small change to the existing reading code.)

You should feel free to request that support (or even a re-evaluation of the decision not to support `-supervised` mode) at the Gensim project issue tracker: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues

In the meantime, if the word-vectors could be separately exported from `FastText` into a format `Gensim` supports, that might be a practical workaround. It looks like the official-from-Facebook Python wrapper for FastText – https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/FastText.py – offers ways to access each word & vector, so that could be loaded & copied into a Gensim `KeyedVectors` instance or otherwise written to a readable disk file.

Roughly (this is untested code):

```py
import fasttext  # as installed by `pip install fasttext`
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

ft_model = fasttext.load_model('ft.bin')
kv = KeyedVectors(vector_size=ft_model.get_dimension())
all_words = ft_model.get_words()
all_vectors = [ft_model.get_word_vector(w) for w in all_words]
kv.add(all_words, all_vectors)
kv.save_word2vec_format('ftwords.txt', binary=False)
```

Comment: I'll try this idea my friend. Awesome 

Comment: I tried this and it worked.. Awesome @gojomo, thanks.. but some minor correction, instead of size, we need to give as vector_size for initializing `KeyedVectors`